# AD ERROR Likes: ERROR CODE[80070005] MSG[Access is denied. ]

Tags: active-directory, locked

Recently, I have tried to test the user while if it was locked or not in AD server, but get this error info `ERROR CODE[80070005] MSG[Access is denied. ]`, I have logined in the AD server and find the user wasnot locked...

I am sorry to know what cause this occur, any ideas are thanks!

Thank you very much and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What action caused this error? Does the action work for another user? An admin user? If your changing group membership in AD remember to re log into the machine.

Comment: Hi, ForverDebugging  I have used the administrator to work on a common user, while this error occur... Thank you very much!

Comment: So you were making changes in ad when you saw the error? Or were you executing .net code?